# django abstract base class with ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, subclass

```
class Question(models.Model):
    answer_choices = models.ManyToManyField(Answers)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class HTMLQuestion(Question):
    question = models.fields.TextField()

class TextQuestion(Question):
    question = models.fields.TextField()

class Quiz(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

The last line doesn't work.  I can't run `python manage.py makemigrations` without the error "Field defines a relation with model 'Question', which is either not installed, or is abstract."

Is there a way to have a list of Question subclassed instances without having it be of type "Question"?  I want to have both types HTMLQuestion and TextQuestions to be in the Quiz.

Comment: Then better you remove the `abstract=True`

Comment: Then HTMLQuestion and TextQuestion would break, and it still wouldn't answer how to get HTMLQ's and TextQ's in the Quiz instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I ended up with was to forget working with inheritance in Django and instead to put the type in the Question and then created functions of how to deal with that type in the Question model itself.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    answer_choices = models.ManyToManyField(Answers)
    question_type = models.fields.TextField() # "htmlquestion", "textquestion"
    
    def how_to_deal_with_type(question_type):
        # code here

class Quiz(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a concrete base class instead of an abstract one, and have a look at https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
This would return the sub-classed items (plain django returns the base class items, which is less useful)

Comment: This works for me with an intermediate model that I needed to derive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you define the Question model as abstract it does not create a table during migration. An abstract model allows you to reuse implementation/fields, but not relations. The ManyToMany field and the ForeignKey field require a table to refer to. In your case you need to handle the many-to-many relation manually by creating a support table similar to the one django creates for you when you use the ManyToMany field. In your particular case it should have four columns:

- id(auto),
- **quiz**(foreign_key),
- **q_type**(if for each type you derived from
  question),
- **q_id**(integer that holds the id of the record you are
  referring).

use the **q_type** to get the concrete model where you will get the **q_id**.

Comment: I don't get the idea of a support table that is controlled by django.  If it's not controlled by django then I'm not looking to control this that way.

Comment: the manytomany field is an abstraction itself. It simply creates a table similar to the one i listed above that handles the the relation. The field object itself is a container that provides the add/remove/list for you. Those translate to operations on the system table. What I am proposing is to dump the automation layer django provides, and do it manually. There is an option to override the ManyToMany field implementation, but it would require better knowledge of the framework, which given your original question I do think you either lack and/or do not wish to build.